# How to create a Class as equivalent of a Class with defined type of RDF Statements?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, shacl

I have three classes, let's call them `:A`, `:B` and `:C` and a property `:p`.

Every statement `X: :p :Y` should become a member of `:A`, when `:X a :B` and `:Y a :C`

Currently I'd prefer a solution with OWL, but could be also with SPARQL and/or SHACL.

Comment: The whole statement `:X :p :Y` shell become a member of`:A`?! Are you talking about reification?

Comment: Yes, so the best solution should generate the statements, but I'd be curious to learn also a solution on pre-generated statements.

Comment: But this is not possible in OWL, isn't it? I'm not an expert but I never heard about asserting ABox axioms to an OWL class. Neither asserted not via inference.

Comment: It might not be possible, that's why I suggested other means such as SHACL. Yet, it might be possible (for example when I "discovered" punning in OWL, I found some unexpected solution - no relation to this case, just explaining why I have hopes)

Comment: What does "become a member of" mean? And I do not see how the title of the question relates to the content of the question. Can you clarify? Note that an RDF triple is not formally related to the class `rdf:Statement`. In fact, nothing formally imposes that `rdf:Statement` contain anything in particular. It could be a class of numbers, a class of programmes, a class of paintings, or a class of utterance. Formally, the triple `:X :p :Y` does not have anything to do with `rdf:Statement` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather ambiguous and quite impossible to parse without intuitive assumptions about what you are trying to express. This may be either due to your choice of being informal in order to avoid complicated precision, or a confusion about the meaning of the RDF and OWL concepts.

The way I interpreted at first the sentence:

> Every statement `X: :p :Y` should become a member of `:A`

was that:

> Every RDF triple of the form `?x :p ?y` (where `?x` and `?y` are any subject and object respectively) can be inferred as a member of class  `:A`.

It is easy to answer the question in this case: it cannot be expressed in any of RDF, RDFS, OWL, SWRL, RIF, SPARQL, SPIN, SHACL. The reason is that it is never possible to constrain any class to contain RDF triples in any of these formalisms and languages. To do so, it would be necessary to have RDF triples as first class citizens in the language.

The confusion, if there is, could be that the class `rdf:Statement` is often incorrectly considered to be the class of RDF triples. `rdf:Statement`, although being described as a way to express statements about statements, is not constrained in any way to contain RDF triples, no matter how you write your data, ontology, query, shape, rule, etc. The class `rdf:Statement` is just, formally, an arbitrary class of resources.

However, looking at the comments and answers, it may very well be possible that my interpretation of your use of "statement" and "become a member" is inappropriate for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious SPARQL solution for free-standing triples:

```
PREFIX    : <http://example.com/ontology#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

CONSTRUCT {
    [] a             :A, rdf:Statement ;
       rdf:subject   ?X ;
       rdf:predicate :p ;
       rdf:object    ?Y
}
WHERE {
    ?X  a  :B .
    ?X :p  ?Y .
    ?Y  a  :C .
}
```

With Jena rules, you could probably use [`makeSkolem(...)`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#builtin-primitives).

Answer (score 0):

**Revised...**  this might not meet your needs, because it's making an inference about an *rdf:Statement*, not a *free-standing triple*.  I can't figure how to do this without reificiation.  Maybe something with named graphs, although that's generally not compatible with OWL implementations.  Maybe you'd like [Blazegraph's "Reification Done Right"](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Reification_Done_Right)

Also, maybe you already know how to do this.

It is asserted that lemonTest is an rdf:Statement.  With Hermit reasoning on, it is inferred that lemonTest is a flavorStatement.

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/ontology#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

[ rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
   owl:imports rdf: ,
               rdfs:
 ] .

:flavor rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

:flavorStatement rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty rdf:object ;
                         owl:someValuesFrom :flavor
                       ] ,
                       [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty rdf:subject ;
                         owl:someValuesFrom :fruit
                       ] ;
    rdfs:subClassOf rdf:Statement .


:fruit rdf:type owl:Class .

:lemon a :fruit .

:lemonTest rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
    rdf:Statement ;
    rdf:object :flavor ;
    rdf:predicate :result ;
    rdf:subject :lemon .

:sour a :flavor .
```

**First attempt:**
I'm not an OWL expert either, but the Hermit reasoner in Protégé doesn’t complain about this:

```
@prefix :      <http://example.com/ontology#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .


:root   a       owl:Class . 

:A      a                rdf:Statement ;
        rdf:subject      :X ;
        rdf:predicate    :p ;
        rdf:object       :Y ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  :root .

:B      rdfs:subClassOf  :root .

:C      rdfs:subClassOf  :root .

:X      a       :B .

:p      a       owl:ObjectProperty .

:Y      a       :C .
```

Comment: In this solution `:A` is an individual, not a class. I would imagine defining `:A` with an `owl:equivalentClass`, each statement N which is made by the nodes and properties according to the condition, after running a reasoner, would become a member of `:A`.

Comment: :A is defined as both an individual and a class in my example, but that doesn't help with the inference you're suggesting

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry, I overlooked the last triple.